# Cobalt - What are the latest feature added in the upstream Cobalt (14.119169)?

Tags: cobalt

We have successfully ported Cobalt broswer for raspi-2 platform.
We have also **replaced existing FFMPEG & OpenMax and ported GStreamer based audio/video decoding functionalities**. 
Verified the default YouTube TV app and it works very well.

As of now we are using **Cobalt 13.111497**. We would like to upgrade to latest upstream Cobalt. It will be helpful if we know the added features with latest.

*Please do suggest if we should refer to any other sources about latest updates in Cobalt if this forum is not the right place.*

Comment: Correct, SO isn't the right place to ask for links to off-site resources. Can't you find release notes on the project's home page and/or repo, wherever those are? Also, are you sure that the browser you mention and the "application container" in the tag you added are the same Cobalt?

Comment: Cobalt is enough like a browser that it is common to be referred to that way...

Comment: Please use cobalt-dev@googlegroups.com for questions about Cobalt that don't contain code.

Comment: Yes. Its the right tag **cobalt** @underscore_d. I posted my question to 'cobalt-dev@googlegroups.com'.  This ticket can be closed.